# JSP compiler shows error when using "+" operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword, string-concatenation, addition

I built a servlet that compiles java code and returns compilation errors (if any).
I'm calling it from an html form where I type the code. The thing is, whenever I use the "+" operator for arithmetic addition or to concatenate strings, it just doesn't like it.

This is my servlet class:

```
@WebServlet("/compiler")
public class Compiler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String code = request.getParameter("codeToCompile").toString();
        String results = this.compile(code);
        sb.append(results);
        out.println(sb);
    }


    private String compile(String codeToCompile){
        String compilationResults = null;
        String toCompile = "class test {" + codeToCompile + "}";

        /*Creating dynamic java source code file object*/
        SimpleJavaFileObject fileObject = new JavaObjectFromString ("ejercicio", toCompile);
        JavaFileObject javaFileObjects[] = new JavaFileObject[]{fileObject} ;

        /*Instantiating the java compiler*/
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        /*Create a diagnostic controller, which holds the compilation problems*/
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

        /*get a standard file manager from compiler, this file manager helps us to customize how a compiler reads and writes to files*/
        StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

        /* Prepare a list of compilation units (java source code file objects) to input to compilation task*/
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(javaFileObjects);

        /*Prepare any compilation options to be used during compilation
        //In this example, we are asking the compiler to place the output files under bin folder.*/
        String[] compileOptions = new String[]{"-d", "c:"} ;
        Iterable<String> compilationOptions = Arrays.asList(compileOptions);

        /*Create a compilation task from compiler by passing in the required input objects prepared above*/
        CompilationTask compilerTask = compiler.getTask(null, stdFileManager, diagnostics, compilationOptions, null, compilationUnits) ;
        /*Perform the compilation by calling the call method on compilerTask object.*/
        boolean status = compilerTask.call();
        /*On compilation failure, we can use the diagnostic collector to read the error messages and log them in specific format.*/
        if (!status){//If compilation error occurs
            /*Iterate through each compilation problem and print it*/
            for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
                compilationResults = "ERROR IN LINE "+ diagnostic.getLineNumber() + ": " + diagnostic.getMessage(new Locale(null));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            compilationResults = "SUCCESS";
        }
        /*Finally close the fileManager instance to flush out anything that is there in the buffer.*/
        try {
            stdFileManager.close() ;//Close the file manager
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return compilationResults;
    }   
}
```

It instantiates a class called "JavaObjectFromString" which looks like this:

```
public class JavaObjectFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject{

    private String contents;
    private String name;

    public JavaObjectFromString(String className, String contents){
        super(URI.create(className.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.contents = contents;
        this.name = className;
    }

    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) throws IOException {
        return this.contents;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I attempt to use the + operator either with Strings or with numbers.

I've been testing different scenarios. For example, some code like this:

```
String someText = "test" + "test";
```

trows **Error on line 1: ';' expected**. Also happens when I use the operator inside a method:

```
public String testMethod(){
      return "test" + "test";
}
```

If I then try:

```
public String testMethod(String one, String two){
      return one + two;
}
```

it throws **Error on line 2: not a statement**

If I do:

```
public int someNumber = 12 + 345;
```

I also get **Error on line 1: ';' expected**

Where in my servlet code am I breaking the + operator??

Comment: Eclipse?  JGrasp?  What's the IDE?

Comment: I'm executing it outside the IDE. I have an html with a form calling the servlet (and using ajax to get and display the results).

Comment: But if I execute it using Eclipse+Tomcat, I get the same kind of errors.

Comment: Try it without the space.    `"test1"+"test2"`

Comment: Nope, still no luck :(
Code not including a + operator gets compiled correctly, with spaces being correctly trimmed by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with concatenation, try `"test1".concat("test2")`

Comment: But arithmetic addition fails as well. The point is that the + operator should be working, as it's a valid java operator. But the compiler is choking on it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. The problem was not in how the servlet handles the code but in how it was sent using ajax to post the form contents. All I needed was to encode the text before sending it:

ajaxObject.send('codigo='+encodeURIComponent(codigo));